# Как сделать переход в начало цикла?

Tags: python

Как в питоне сделать переход в начало цикла:

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
  a = random.randint(0, 2)
  b = random.randint(0, 2)
if a == 0 or b == 0:
  # переход в начало цикла
else:
  a / b
```

Comment: Какая должна быть логика работы? Пока никакой нет, цикл бесконечен. Опишите задачу.

Comment: Вообще продолжение цикла делается ключевым словом `continue`, но цикл у вас и правда получится бесконечный

Comment: Чтобы перейти в начало цикла, надо брать в цикле. А if тут не в цикле. Нужно просто обращать внимание на отступы.

Comment: Вы пишите на питоне, а значит если у вас начинается цикл, то все, что внутри цикла выделяется 4 пробелами в начале каждой строки внутри цикла. 
Если вам надо чтобы при определенном условии что-то выполнилось, укажите условие и после него  действие, при успешной проверке условия.
Если условие не выполняется, то вы можете больше ничего не описывать, так как программа пойдет на следующую часть цикла. Просто он у вас действительно бесконечный.

Answer (score 1):

Так как из Вашего вопроса совершенно непонятно, чего Вы хотите добиться, а код содержит странные выражения, сыграем в телепатов. Предположим, что Вы хотите получить два случайных числа неравных нулю, поделить одно на другое и вывести ответ на экран. Тогда, например:

```
while not ((a := random.randint(0, 2)) or (b := random.randint(0, 2)):
    pass
print (a / b)
```

Или воспользоваться предложениями коллег из комментариев к этому ответу.

Если же Вам просто необходимо понять пиинцип работы цикла `while`, то он (цикл) «переходит в начало цикла» сам по себе, на каждой итерации, когда доходит до конца своего блока. Далее, проверяется условие, если оно верно, блок выполняется снова, если неверно, цикл прекращается. Чтобы заставить Ваш цикл работать, надо, во-первых, исправить отступы, чтобы внести условие внутрь цикла и во-вторых, сделать так, чтобы выражение `a/b` имело бы какой-то результат.
Например:

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
  a = random.randint(0, 2)
  b = random.randint(0, 2)
  if a != 0 and b != 0:
      print (a / b)
      loop = 0  
  # переход в начало цикла
```

Comment: В общем-то, цикл не нужен, если просто написать `a = random.randint(1, 2)  b = random.randint(1, 2)`

Comment: @MBo блин, точно!

Comment: `a, b = random.choices(range(1, 3), k=2)`

Comment: @АлексейР прекрасно! Осталось понять, то ли имел ввиду автор :)

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov "что имел в виду автор" - это вечный вопрос :)